# how to group dictionaries using itemgetter

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
students = [
    {'name': 'alex','class': 'A'},
    {'name': 'richard','class': 'A'},
    {'name': 'john','class': 'C'},
    {'name': 'harry','class': 'B'},
    {'name': 'rudolf','class': 'B'},
    {'name': 'charlie','class': 'E'},
    {'name': 'budi','class': 'C'},
    {'name': 'gabriel','class': 'B'},
    {'name': 'dessy', 'class': 'B'}
]
```

I would like to group these dictionaries by class, append them to a list and append each list to a list:

```
[[{'name': 'alex', 'class': 'A'},
 {'name': 'richard', 'class': 'A'}],
 [{'name': 'harry', 'class': 'B'},
 {'name': 'rudolf', 'class': 'B'},
 {'name': 'gabriel', 'class': 'B'},
 {'name': 'dessy', 'class': 'B'}],
 [{'name': 'john', 'class': 'C'},
 {'name': 'budi', 'class': 'C'}],
 [{'name': 'charlie', 'class': 'E'}]]
```

I know how to sort the previous list, using itemgetter:

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter
students = sorted(students, key=itemgetter('class'))
```

How can I group-append them in a list and create a list of lists? Also, would using sets be better in this case (order would not matter, as long as the dictionaries are grouped by class).

Comment: Did you try writing a `for` loop to do this?

Comment: Whether using sets would be better depends on what you intend to do with the result.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for i in students:
    res[i['class']].append(i)
print(list(res.values()))
```

Output

```
[[{'name': 'alex', 'class': 'A'}, {'name': 'richard', 'class': 'A'}],
 [{'name': 'john', 'class': 'C'}, {'name': 'budi', 'class': 'C'}],
 [{'name': 'harry', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'rudolf', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'gabriel', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'dessy', 'class': 'B'}],
 [{'name': 'charlie', 'class': 'E'}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` to the rescue:

```
In [37]: from itertools import groupby

In [38]: from operator import itemgetter

In [39]: students.sort(key=itemgetter('class'))

In [40]: [list(v) for _, v in groupby(students, itemgetter('class'))]
Out[40]:
[[{'name': 'alex', 'class': 'A'}, {'name': 'richard', 'class': 'A'}],
 [{'name': 'harry', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'rudolf', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'gabriel', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'dessy', 'class': 'B'}],
 [{'name': 'john', 'class': 'C'}, {'name': 'budi', 'class': 'C'}],
 [{'name': 'charlie', 'class': 'E'}]]
```

you also could, if you wanted to, key off class in a dict:

```
In [41]: {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(students, itemgetter('class'))}
Out[41]:
{'A': [{'name': 'alex', 'class': 'A'}, {'name': 'richard', 'class': 'A'}],
 'B': [{'name': 'harry', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'rudolf', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'gabriel', 'class': 'B'},
  {'name': 'dessy', 'class': 'B'}],
 'C': [{'name': 'john', 'class': 'C'}, {'name': 'budi', 'class': 'C'}],
 'E': [{'name': 'charlie', 'class': 'E'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it "manually":

```
students = [
    {'name': 'alex','class': 'A'},
    {'name': 'richard','class': 'A'},
    {'name': 'john','class': 'C'},
    {'name': 'harry','class': 'B'},
    {'name': 'rudolf','class': 'B'},
    {'name': 'charlie','class': 'E'},
    {'name': 'budi','class': 'C'},
    {'name': 'gabriel','class': 'B'},
    {'name': 'dessy', 'class': 'B'}
]

classes = dict()

for student in students:
    if student['class'] not in classes:
        classes[student['class']] = []
    classes[student['class']].append(student['name'])
    
all = []
for classroom in sorted(classes.keys()):
    all.append([])
    
    for student in classes[classroom]:
        all[-1].append({'name':student,'class':classroom})
    
print (all)
```